Multivariable limit: $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x + y}}$
I need to evaluate the following limit, which I suspect does not exist:.$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x + y}}$$
I tried to find different curves such that: $\gamma(t_0) = (0,0)$, but $\lim_{t \to t_0} f(\gamma(t))$ is different. The problem is that I was only able to find paths which the limit is $0$.
A friend advised me to explore different level curves to find an alternative curve where the limit might differ. However, I encountered a problem. For $c$-level curves, I found that: $$(\frac{c^2 - \sqrt{c^4+4t^3c^2}}{2t^2},t)$$ These curves are not continuous at $t_0=0$, making them seem unhelpful at first.
In summary, I need help finding a different path that yields a distinct limit. Additionally, I'd appreciate an explanation of the reasoning behind choosing such a path—please don’t just provide the curve, but also explain why it works. Thanks in advance.

How do you define the square root when $x+y<0$?

It is not defined for $\mathbb{R}$. What is the suggestion? Find curves so that $x+y < 0$?

I am just suggesting that the problem should state that $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ from within the half-plane $x+y> 0$.

As said in the comments, $(x,y)$ must approach $(0,0)$ from within the half-plane $x+y>0$.
Let $$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x+y}}$$
and
$$\gamma(t)=(t,-t+t^4)$$
Observe that $\gamma(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})$ belongs to $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\:|\:x+y>0\}$ and that $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$. Clearly
$$f(\gamma(t))=\frac{t(-t+t^4)}{\sqrt{t-t+t^4}}=\frac{-t^2+t^5}{t^2}=-1+t^3$$
So
$$\lim_{t\to 0}f(\gamma(t))=\lim_{t\to 0}(-1+t^3)=-1$$
Since you've already found lots of paths leading to a zero limit, this proves that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x+y}}$$
does not exist.

How did I find the curve $\gamma$? I tried to look for a curve of the form
$$\gamma(t)=(t,a_1t+a_2t^2+\ldots+a_nt^n)$$
for some integer $n>1$ and some $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb R$. Just note that $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$ and that
$$f(\gamma(t))=\frac{a_1t^2+a_2t^3+a_3t^4+a_4t^5+\ldots+a_nt^{n+1}}{\sqrt{(a_1+1)t+a_2t^2+\ldots+a_nt^n}}$$
Since we want a limit which is different from zero when $t\to 0$, we wish that $f(\gamma(t))$ could be written as
\begin{equation}
f(\gamma(t))=c+O(t^k)\qquad (\blacktriangle)
\end{equation}
where $c\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is a constant different from zero and $k\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$. If we choose the coefficients $a_i$ in a way that $a_1+1,a_2,a_3,a_5,\ldots,a_n=0$ and $a_4\neq 0$ (for example $a_4=1$) then the only term surviving under the square root is the $4$th-order term, leading to
$$f(\gamma(t))=\frac{-t^2+t^5}{\sqrt{t^4}}$$
which is great, since it can be rewritten in the form $(\blacktriangle)$ we were looking for.

Great answer, thank you very much!
